# mysql days between two dates group by month

Tags: mysql

i am trying to group days between two date filters by month. Is it possible to do this in mysql.

```
Example : StartDate : 2012-01-19  EndDate: 2012-03-24
```

The query should return days grouped by month

```
Jan : 19
Feb  : 29
Mar :24
Apr : 0
May : 0 etc
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way there are 29 days in Feb-2012 :)

Comment: Before I write some code for you, are you sure that you want to use only MySQL? Because if you're only counting the days of the months, you can do that with just PHP and leave MySQL out of it. If there is some way of identifying the exact days you want to count, please tell me now before I give a solution.

Comment: Oh yes of course 29 days in Feb :) Unfortunately, I would need to do it using MySql only , even though this may make it a bit complex. I was wondering if we can use a GROUP BY , but the problem with that is that it only considers the month of the start date and not the corresponding months. Would really appreciate any help/suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this query will work for you for a limited date range(past 1,00,000 days). but better way would be to write a separate function or procedure with `WHILE` loop.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(_date, '%M') AS month,
       COUNT(1) AS days
FROM (
        SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) DAY AS _date
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS d
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS e
     ) a
WHERE _date BETWEEN '2012-01-19' AND '2012-03-24'
GROUP BY MONTH(_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(_date);
```

New answer for your question in comment: just had a question, how can I do a JOIN to another table using this query. The basic idea is I have a Bookings table which has a startDate and an endDate, and using these as parameters for the _date BETWEEN , I need to find out the number of days for each month. Any suggestions on how I could do that? Also is it possible to return the results in a single row rather than multiple rows:

see [SQL FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37004/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Bookings (
  start_date date DEFAULT NULL,
  end_date date DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Bookings(start_date, end_date)VALUES('2012-01-19','2012-03-24'),('2012-01-05','2012-08-21');

SELECT b.*,
(
 SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(b.start_date, '%M:'), (DATEDIFF(LAST_DAY(b.start_date), b.start_date) + 1), ',',
               GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(first_day, '%M:'),days)), ',',
               DATE_FORMAT(b.end_date, '%M:%d')
              ) AS total_days
FROM(
             SELECT DATE_FORMAT(_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS first_day,
                    COUNT(1) AS days
             FROM (
                    SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) DAY AS _date
                    FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS d
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS e
                 ) a, (SELECT @cnt := 0) b
              GROUP BY YEAR(_date), MONTH(_date)
             ) a
             WHERE first_day BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(b.start_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(b.end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        ) total_days
FROM Bookings b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) What do you mean by works for a limited date range? Will it work only for dates within the same year?

Comment: it will work for past 1000 days only but you can extend date range to 10000, 100000,... just by adding one more `CROSS JOIN`s which should be sufficient for you.

Comment: If you got your answer then don't forget to accept the best answer.

Comment: I will do that as it works perfectly on its own, just had a question, how can I do a JOIN to another table using this query. The basic idea is I have a Bookings table which has a startDate and an endDate, and using these as parameters for the _date BETWEEN , I need to find out the number of days for each month. Any suggestions on how I could do that?

Comment: Also is it possible to return the results in a single row rather than multiple rows

Comment: Thanks, just checked. Its returning the result in a single column as total_days. Actually what I meant was : have a single row for each booking: So it would be something like this  BookingId StartDate EndDate Jan Feb Mar April May... as separate columns , as I need to use those days to calculate monthly revenues.

Comment: I have tried using a stored procedure ,but the problem with that is , I cannot include it as a subquery in a SELECT statement

Comment: dynamic number of columns in output is not possible with single query. for that you need to write a complex stored procedure using cursor with dynamic sql. you can easily extract those comma separated values from php client using explode function.

Comment: Oh okay. Actually, I need those values for a report that i am working on using iReport Designer, so I needed it to be done using MySQL itself. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing an issue with the selected answer, try this, works great with MySQL 5.7+ defaults:

```
SELECT
 YEAR(_date) AS year,
 MONTH(_date) AS month,
       COUNT(1) AS days
FROM (
        SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) DAY AS _date
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS d
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS e
     ) a
WHERE _date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-10-11'
GROUP BY YEAR(_date), MONTH(_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(_date);
```